# SQL Statements Extractor in Java class

Tags: java, sql, parsing, extract

I have a lot of java components which are connecting Oracle database and execute DML commands.
I look for which java module using which Oracle objects.

I want to extract SQL statements but statements are various.

For example;

```
StringBuilder or StringBuffer named sb
sb.append("select * from oracle_table");
sb.append("inner join oracle_table2");
(PreparedStatement p).executeQuery(sb);
```

or all of sql statement in a single String variable.
or hibernate.

Like this select statement there are update,delete,insert statements.

So I want to find final concatenated SQL statements. Maybe then I can find which java module using which  Oracle objects.

Is there any plugin,ide,application,tool,java or other language code,etc for this operation?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. You could use String objects that define the query and only define them in the relative classes, this might be unmaintainable. Another option would be to use an enum to force immutability but this would also become unmaintainable fast. Another option, like you stated, is Hibernate which would solve your problem but adds a layer of complexity and difficulty so there is a learning curve. A simple option would be to simple define the queries in a file type like Properties or JSON.

Properties

```
query.user.select = SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ?;
```

JSON

```
[
    {
        "name": "user.select",
        "query": "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = ?;"
    }
]
```

```java
class NamedQuery {

    private final String name;

    private final String query;

}
```

Then you could create some immutable class composed of these NamedQuery objects.

```java
class QueryService {

    // use ImmutableSet to enforce immutability
    private final Set<NamedQuery> queries;

    // constructor (create from JSON file using GSON for example)
    public QueryService(Set<NamedQuery> queries) {
        this.queries = queries;
    }

    public NamedQuery get(String name) {
        // get for name, could even use a Map for faster lookup if needed
    }

}
```

Comment: I had thousands Java class and queries. I dont want to find manuelly this. Also I dont run this codes for this operations. I want to scan files offline.

Comment: If thats the case it might be in your best interest to look into JOOQ or Hibernate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is there anyone have other ideas?